# Problem accessing web based email with Firefox

Tags: firefox, yahoo

I am running Natty Narwhal and all of a sudden I am unable to access any web based email (like Yahoo mail) I enter my user name & password and hit the login button and the page that loads keeps resetting really fast and never finishes loading.  the URL keeps changing with each reset. if I did not know any better I would assume that it was trying every user name/password combination to attempt to get illegal access to an/my account. However I have been able to bypass that using the Tor browser so I know that is is local to MY copy of Firefox but I do not know what files to replace/remove/edit to fix this problem. Yes I have done a virus scan with Clam Anti virus and found nothing. Please someone HELP!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reconfigure firefox

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firefox
```

Also I would check the proxy server settings of firefox. Maybe you can as well try firefox from another user account as the firefox in there might have another configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's a proxy setting thing. Go to 'Edit' in your Firefox page and select 'Preferences'. Click 'Advanced' and under 'Connection' checked 'Auto-detect proxy for this network' and click OK.Close the page and restart Firefox.Thanks.